# Use Landsat5 dataset to calculate temperature got wrong value in GEE

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I use GEE to calculate the temperature by Landsat5 dataset ([the dataset description](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LT05_C02_T1_L2#bands)).

You can follow the example to generate the temperature.

Here is my code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/78d59ff12bec5e9c39d9c9e0d4a523ff

As you can see the lowest temperature is below -40. It's not right for the area. It should be 15+℃。

Here is the vector link in my code : https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/cgl/fuzhou

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the gap... The Landsat5 images of research area have a lot cloud. So, I removed the cloud pixel. The result got right:)